# Fermat's Little Theorem proof attempt

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I read a wrong proof of the Fermat's Little Theorem, and I would like to know if it is possible to "repair" it.

The theorem is the following:

If $p$ is prime and $a\ne0$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv1 \pmod p$.

The proof should follow three steps:

1. $\exists 1\le m\le (p-1) : a^m\equiv1\pmod p$
2. Take the minimum of such $m$'s. Then $m\vert (p-1)$.
3. Since $p-1=km$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $a^{p-1}= a^{km}=\left(a^{m}\right)^{k}\equiv1^k\equiv1\pmod p$.

Proof attempts:

1. Let consider $a$ as elements of the group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and take $a^0, a^1, \dots, a^p$. Since they are $p+1$ elements in a group of order $p$ there must be $i,j$ with $i<j$ such that $a^i\equiv a^j\pmod p$. From that we have $a^{j-i}\equiv 1\mod p$. So we can take $m=j-i$. However such $m$ is greater than $0$ since $j>i$ but we cannot say that $m\le (p-1)$.
2. This is the most controversial point. The proof I read supposes that $m\nmid (p-1)$. Then $$p-1=km+r$$ whith $1\le r \le m-1$, so $$a^{p-1}=a^{km+r}=a^{km}\cdot a^r\equiv a^r\pmod p$$ and it concludes that it has to be $r=m-1$ (but why?) and from that $p=m(k+1)$ in contradiction  with the primality of $p$.
3. The third step is clear and it works, but it is based on the second step which is fallacious.

Am I wrong saying that this proof cannot work? And eventually, could it be adjusted to work?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say the proof is 'wrong' as such, but it might be unclear and lacking details.

EDIT: I prove part 2) in a slightly different manner - don't know how exactly to fix the proof you present.

First, for 1., don't include $a^0$, as that is already $1$. Also, there are *$n$* elements in a group of order $n$, by definition, and one of them is $1$, so you just need $a,a^2,\dots,a^{p-1}$ to be sure you are hitting $1$, because if not, $a^i=a^j$ and so $a^{j-i}\equiv 1$, wlog $j>i$ and $j-i\leq p-1$.

For 2., I believe we want to use Lagrange's theorem, i.e. $a^{|G|}=1$ for any $a\in G$ where $G$ is a finite group. Then $1\equiv a^{p-1} \equiv a^r$, but $m$ was minimal with this property, a contradiction to $r\leq m-1$. Here we are of course considering $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, which has order $p-1$.

Comment: For the first point you are right, even if (maybe) it would not be a problem (for the rest of the proof) to have $m$ outside $(1,...,p-1)$.

For the second point it is not clear to me how do you apply Lagrange's Theorem. The multiplicative order of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ should be $p-1$ and it would be $1\equiv a^{p-1}\equiv a^r$. Anyway Lagrange's Theorem cannot be applied in this proof.

Comment: I have made some smaller corrections to my answer, hopefully it is more clear now. But why should we not be able to apply Lagrange?

Comment: Because this theorem has been presented in the course before the Lagrange's one. And also because with Lagrange's theorem, the first step wouldn't have been necessaray. Fermat's little theorem would be followed directly.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you provide a source to the proof? Then I might be able to give a better answer.